# PhpStorm, open files depending on the git branch

Tags: git, branch, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I work, I always have 2 to 6/7/... branches where I edit usually completely different files. These branches usually don't exist for more than a few days, 2 or 3 weeks at most.

As I don't want to look for the files I modified or had opened last time I worked on one particular branch, I'd like to have some sort of solution, maybe a plugin, for this problem.

Maybe I'm missing a functionality of PhpStorm (or Webstorm,IntelliJ,..)
Or maybe there is a plugin for this?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such functionality ATM (remembering last edited files per branch). But It's possible to remember such files per task/ticket https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Integration+with+an+Issue+Tracking+System+in+PhpStorm

Comment: In any case: as general solution I may suggest to try `Context` functionality (set of files which you can switch to/open in one click) -- `Tools | Tasks & Contexts | Save/Load Context...`  ( https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/managing-tasks-and-context.html?search=context )

Comment: this does work perfectly for my needs, thank you! (I still let the question open, for people who dont work with issuetrackers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/manage-branches.html), it is possible to restore workspace on branch switching :

> PhpStorm saves your context (a set of opened files, the current run configuration, and breakpoints ) provided that the Restore workspace on branch switching option is enabled in the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S) under Version Control | Confirmation. When you switch to a branch, PhpStorm automatically restores your context associated with that branch.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question after three years. It has been resolved in the comments ever since, but it is good to have an officially accepted answer!